# Slick function for filtering an Array of Objects

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have an Array of Objects:

```
{Option1: true, Option2: true, Option3: true}
```

I want to **filter** this array so that only true elements remain. But i need the key, not the value. How can i do this?

I searched for an **underscore.js** function, but they do this only for the values, not the keys.

Comment: Loop through the array and safe only those keys which contain `"true"` as a value.

Comment: There's the `.filter()` function available on the native Array prototype. Your array syntax is invalid - what does it really look like?

Comment: Your syntax is invalid by the way.

Comment: Does not it should like this `[{"key1":"false"}, {"key2":"true"}]`?

Comment: This is not an array. It is an object with multiple properties.

Comment: `_.reduce(obj, function(memo, val, key){if(val) memo[key] = val;  return memo;}, {})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var keys = [{"key1":"false"}, {"key2":"true"}]
        .filter(function (o, i) { return o['key' + (i + 1)] === 'true'; })
        .map(function (o) { for (var k in o) return k; });

console.log(keys); //["key2"]
```

EDIT:

You changed the question... `{Option1: true, Option2: true, Option3: true}` is not an array of objects, it's simply an object. Here's what you could do:

```
var o = {Option1: true, Option2: true, Option3: true};

var keys = Object.keys(o).filter(function (k) {
    return o[k];
});
```

Answer (score 1):

First, this is not an array of objects.

This is an array of objects:

```
ax =
[ {Option1: true, Option2: true, Option3: true},
  {Option1: true, Option2: true, Option3: true},
  {Option1: true, Option2: true, Option3: true} ]
```

To filter it iterate and test. If it passes your criteria, copy it into a result set:

```
result = [];

for (i = 0; i < ax.length; i++)
{
  if (ax[i].Option2) // may be as complex as you need it to be
  {
    // passed test
    result.push(ax[i]);
  }
}
```

Now `result` contains the items you want.